# If/els doesnt work in my code in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I did this code, and if you doesn't insert any columns, instead of printing "Insert columns please" I want that prints the minimum, maximum and average of all the columns, as if you've inserted all in the incial code.

I tried writing

```
if["$col"=""]; then $col=`seq 5 20`
```

but it doesn't work. Any help please??

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg; do
    case "$1" in
        -[0-9]*) col+="${1#-}"",";;
        -g) shift
            gene="$1";;
        [a-z]*) file="$1";;


    esac
    shift
done
echo col="$col" gene="$gene" file="$file"


OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","; 

echo "$col"

if ["$col" == ""]; 

    then echo "Insert columns please"   
else

    for i in $col; do   

    echo

    echo minim columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" "$file" | tr -s '  ' ' ' |tr -s ',' '.' | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | sort -n | head -1`
    echo maxim columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" "$file" | tr -s '  ' ' ' |tr -s ',' '.' | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | sort -n | tail -1`
    echo average columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" "$file" | tr -s '  ' ' ' |tr -s ',' '.' | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/NR}'`

    shift
    done
fi

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: `[` is not a part of syntax but a alias for `test` command

Answer (score 3):

Spaces around `[` and `]` are mandatory, so instead of:

```
if ["$col" == ""];
```

Have this:

```
if [ "$col" = "" ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if [ "$col" = "" ]; then $col=`seq 5 20`
```

Bash if test statements require space after the opening `[` and before the closing `]`

Answer (score 0):

> Have this:
>
> ```
>  if ["$col" == ""];
> ```

The latest GNU versions of the external "test" command and his fork "[" accept the "==" operator. This is equivalent to "=".

```
[ ~]$ str="things"
[ ~]$ [ "$str" == "things" ] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"
YES
```

As well as internal Bash/KSH instruction :

```
[ ~]$ [[ $str == things ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"
YES
```

(which is not an external command and which is better if you use only GNU Bash 3+ or KSH 88+).

Furthermore, it's indeed necessary to write spaces either side of the symbols "[" and "]". The operands are arguments to external command (or internal instruction when you use the [[ syntax). Otherwise it will be interpreted as an unknown command shell.